# Easiest way to check record is exist or not in Linq to Entity Query

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

in store procedure we can check record is exist or not using following query for fast performance

```
if EXISTS ( Select 1 from Table_Name where id=@id )
```

But what about Linq query.
right now i have to store whole data in object like this

```
UserDetail _U=db.UserDetails.where(x=>x.id==1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any Solution?

Comment: Use Linq Any ie `bool exist=db.UserDetails.Any(x=>x.id==1);`

Answer (score 6):

Use Linq's `Any` ie `bool exist = db.UserDetails.Any(x => x.id == 1);`

```cs
if(db.UserDetails.Any(x => x.id == 1)) {
    var userDetail = db.UserDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
}
```

Comment: can we use `if(db.UserDetails.where(x => x.id == 1).count()>0) { }`

Comment: Yes you can use that as well

Comment: @ManishVadher don't use count, it will fetch all data and apply count on that. `Any` is always better than count.

Comment: @Imad, no, the count will get executed on the SQL server as it is part of the queryable. If there was a `.ToList().Count()`, then yes, it would fetch the set, but not as was written

Comment: @ManishVadher   What If db.UserDetails is null ?

Comment: @NitinJain you need to set default value in dbcontext file like =new UserDetails();

Answer (score 2):

```
bool exist = db.UserDetails.Where(x=>x.id==1).Any();
if(exist){
  //your-code
 }else{
  //your-code
}
```

Comment: You must capitalize `W` in `where` and `A` in `any`.

Answer (score 1):

Just check

```
if(_U == null)
```

This way you will get what you want in single query and you not need to execute addition query like

```
db.UserDetails.Any(x => x.id == 1)
```

Comment: i think using `if(UserDetail _U == null)` all data store into _U and then we have to check `null` condition. so that unnecessary data store in _U.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it does not require to fire two query. It can be accomplish by single query.

```
UserDetails objUserDetails =db.UserDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
if(objUserDetails==null)
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // do something with objUserDetails
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var qry = db.User_Detail.Where(x => x.User_Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();

if(qry !=null)
{
// Do something
}
else
{
return false;
}
```

Try This...